# How can I upload a file larger than 32MB to GCS using the google-cloud client?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-python

I recently started using [google-cloud client](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python), and I made this little example (I have omitted/changed things for clarity's sake):

```html
<form id="testform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p>
    <div>
      <label for="fotos">Some file</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="file" name="testfile">
    </div>
  </p>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

```py
from google.cloud import storage

class MyHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("test.html")

    def post(self):
        file = self.request.POST["testfile"]
        filename = file.filename # + TimeStamp

        bucket = storage.Client().get_bucket(self.get_bucket_name())
        blob = bucket.blob(filename)

        blob.upload_from_string(data=file.file.read(),
                                content_type=file.type)

        self.write(blob.public_url)
```

This code works just fine with anything under 32MB, but it cannot handle larger files because they go through the app instead of directly to GCS. I have seen [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898736/upload-file-bigger-than-40mb-to-google-app-engine) using the Blobstore API, but those are old and the Blobstore isn't even used to store the data anymore (though the Blobstore API can still be used).

So I was wondering, is there a way to fix this using the google-cloud client? I have not seen a method to create an upload url in the [docs](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/storage-buckets.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client should upload directly to GCS. A single connection from a GAE can't transfer more than 32 MB.

This shouldn't be a problem to you because you are already using a HTML form. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object

You may have to make the bucket publicly accessible depending on the access you'll need for your app. Else you'll have to specify `GoogleAccessId` in the `PUT` request generated on your backend and sent to frontend beforehand.

There is a small form upload example at the end of the page linked above.

Finally, I personally recommend to use AJAX to upload your file using the REST API https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload This will help you handle errors, redirects and success easier.

Comment: The JSON API sounds like a great solution. So I guess I don't really need that google-cloud client. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Jorge, can you point me in a direction as to how to use the JSON API via ajax to upload a file. I've been reading the docs all day but have not found a concrete example. I just need a nudge in the right direction. Cheers