# Upload large files to Google Cloud Storage using Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, google-appengine-node

I would like to upload files up to 1GB to Google Cloud Storage. I'm using Google App Engine Flexible. From what I understand, GAE has a 32MB limit on file uploads, which means I have to either upload directly to GCS or break the file into chunks.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6899157/3715136) from several years ago suggests using the Blobstore API, however there doesn't seem to be an option for Node.js and the documentation also recommends using GCS instead of Blobstore to store files.

After doing some searching, it seems like using signed urls to upload directly to GCS may be the best option, but I'm having trouble finding any example code on how to do this. Is this the best way and are there any examples of how to do this using App Engine with Node.js?

Comment: I think this library is what you are looking for https://www.npmjs.com/package/gcs-signed-urls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use the Cloud Storage client library for Node.js to create a [resumable upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/performing-resumable-uploads).

Here's the [official](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#createResumableUpload) code example on how to create the session URI:

```
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const myBucket = storage.bucket('my-bucket');

const file = myBucket.file('my-file');
file.createResumableUpload(function(err, uri) {
  if (!err) {
    // `uri` can be used to PUT data to.
  }
});

//-
// If the callback is omitted, we'll return a Promise.
//-
file.createResumableUpload().then(function(data) {
  const uri = data[0];
});
```

Edit: It seems you can nowadays use the [createWriteStream](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#createWriteStream) method to perform an uplaod without having to worry about creation of a URL.

Comment: What do you next with the URI?

Comment: When you have the URI you need to make a PUT request to it (it's described a little further down in the first link). I've updated the answer because it seems nowadays you can bypass all that with the createWriteStream method.